# jQuery drag&drop item automatically go to placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I got the following structure:

[image]

**The problem:**

The `draggable items` should be dropped at the placeholder. Every draggable item has a class (red, blue, green, etc) and only the placeholder with the same color accepts it. My question is how I can make when a draggable item is dropped in the yellow box it should automatically go in its placeholder: e.g. u put the red item in the yellow box and the placeholder should accept it. Currently to make placeholder accept the item you should drag the item exactly over the placeholder.

**My researches:**

I've checked pretty much everything in the http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ and http://jqueryui.com/droppable/, couldn't find similar examples.

**Code:**
My code is just a simple

```
element.droppable({
    accept: "[cat='" + attrs.droppable + "']",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            //on drop code
    }
});
```

together with

```
element.draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        //code

    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        //etc
    }
})
```

Am I missing something in the documentation?

I would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. Only make the yellow box droppable, and then reposition the dragged item to the appropriate placeholder box inside.

```
$("#yellowBox").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    drop: handleDrop
});

function handleDrop( event, ui ) {

  // Get the color of the dragged element
  var draggedColor = ui.draggable.attr ('class');

   ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
   ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );

    // Reposition to the placeholder box with the same color
   ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this,'.'+draggedColor), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
   ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
}
```